# How to set bold only to first level list elements?

Tags: html, css

How to set bold style with CSS only to the "titles" in this code?

Live example: [jsbin.com/xofudovoda/](http://jsbin.com/xofudovoda/edit?html,css,output)

```css
.container > ol {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ol type="I">
    <li>
      Title 1
      <ol>
        <li>sub 1</li>
        <li>sub 2</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      Title 2
      <ol>
        <li>sub 1</li>
        <li>sub 2</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set bold on first level `<ol>`, and reset it on the second level `<ol>`s.

```css
.container ol {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.container ol ol {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ol type="I">
    <li>
      Title 1
      <ol>
        <li>sub 1</li>
        <li>sub 2</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      Title 2
      <ol>
        <li>sub 1</li>
        <li>sub 2</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ol li { font-weight: 700 }
ol li ol li {font-weight: 300 }
```

Comment: Hi this is the correct answer try to improve it with a snippet an example and complement with the explanation :)

Comment: hi. ol will select all <ol>s on the page then select all <li>s inside the <ol> and set them bold style, then on the second line is the same, but it will select all <ol>s inside another <ol>s and set their <li>s the normal font style.
Why to explain such a basic things?

Comment: Hi, why ? if OP is asking it's beacuse he doesn't know even if it seems so simple to you, you must explain to make more valious your answer. not just drop code here I just suggest it to you to give more precedence to your answer you answer first and was correct, but why wasn't choose as the answer ? because it lacks of content .... It's just a suggest :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following CSS:

```
.container ol li {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container ol li ol li{
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
li
{
  font-weight:normal;
}
.container > ol>li {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Add a rule for li. That forces the child `<li>` elements to use their own style instead of inheriting it from their parent.

Answer (score 1):

Set all the `li` to font-weight normal, then only apply the bolding to direct children of the original `ol`.

```css
li {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.container > ol:first-child > li {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<ol type="I">
  <li>
    Title 1
    <ol>
      <li>sub 1</li>
      <li>sub 2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    Title 2
    <ol>
      <li>sub 1</li>
      <li>sub 2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Comment: why you need the first-child selector ?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you've got ordered lists nested within the li's you're trying to target specifically. Try the following:

```css
.container > ol > li {
  font-weight: bold;
  }
.container > ol > li ol {
  font-weight: normal;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<ol type="I">
  <li>
    Title 1
    <ol>
      <li>sub 1</li>
      <li>sub 2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    Title 2
    <ol>
      <li>sub 1</li>
      <li>sub 2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Or, another way:

```css
.container li {
  font-weight: bold;
  }
.container > ol > li > ol > li {
  font-weight: normal;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<ol type="I">
  <li>
    Title 1
    <ol>
      <li>sub 1</li>
      <li>sub 2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    Title 2
    <ol>
      <li>sub 1</li>
      <li>sub 2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nth-child will make bold **first** sub items of each,

```
ol> li> ol>li:nth-child(odd){
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Edit 1: 
Sorry I understood wrong, this may help.

```
 ol>li {
    font-weight:bold;
}

ol > li > ol > li {
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

Hope helps,

Comment: this will bold the sub 1 and not the title

Comment: @VivekTankaria yea miss understood. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take the Title in span tag and than to that span apply **font-weight:bold** `ol >li > span {font-weight:bold;}` 
working example : http://jsbin.com/gifaliluve/edit?html,css,output

Here is the code :

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<style>
ol >li > span {font-weight:bold;}
</style>
</head>
<div class="container">
<ol type="I">
  <li>
    <span>Title 1</span>
    <ol>
      <li>sub 1</li>
      <li>sub 2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Title 1</span>
    <ol>
      <li>sub 1</li>
      <li>sub 2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```